# Android rxJava - Null object wrapped in Observable

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a use case that is as simple as this: Look for a Book in the Remote source, if it doesn't exist, create it.
So this is my approach that used to work with rxJava1:

```
public void handleBook(int id) {
    getBookById(id) 
        .flatMap(new Func1<Book, Observable<Book>> {
            @Override
            public Observable<Book> call(Book book) {
                if(book != null) // it exists
                ...
                else // it's null - it doesn't exist ...
            }
        }
}


public Observable<Book> getBookById(int id) {
    Book book = remoteSource.book(id)
    return Observable.just(book)
}
```

In this case if the object `book` is null, the Observable.just call throws an exception. It's explicitly checking against null values. 
Back for rxJava 1 I could pass a null as value to Observable.just (or other accesoars), then in the map or flatMap operators I'd check if the value I get is null (meaning result does not exist) or not (meaning I got some result).

With this limitation it seems that I cannot do this check anymore. I tried returning Observable.empty() in case the `book` object is null but then the whole thread would *complete* and finish when the returned value is Observable.empty().

How can I check in a rx-chain of execution if something I need is there and branch the chain of execution afterwards?

Comment: Either use `Single` and check for errors or wrap the book object inside an `Optional`

Comment: can you tell me more about the first option? Using Single..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Observable<Book>` as a return type use `Single<Book>`. [`Single`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#single) type emits either an object or an error

**NOTE:** Right now I don't have an IDE so the code will probably have some compiler fails. I assume you'll fix it easily

```
public Single<Book> getBookById(int id) {
    return Single.create((e) => {
        Book book = remoteSource.book(id)
        if (book != null)
            e.emit(book);
        else
            e.fail();
    }
}

public void handleBook(int id) {
    getBookById(id) 
        .onErrorResume(e => createBook(...))
        ...
}
```

Like a said earlier I'm not sure about the exact code but you can read it as if it was pseudo-code

Comment: `Single.fromCallable` would be better than `Single.create`

Comment: why this does it have to do with Single ? Observable can be solution for this also. But, the problem here is that "onErrorResumeNext" would execute anyway, whether there's an error or not. So it's not applicable as a solution :-/

Comment: As far as I know the body of `onErrorResumeNext` is only executed if an exception was thrown. Which is what happens if the book fetched is null. `Single` is more appropiate for this than `Observable` since `Observable` is a flow of 0..N items and `Single` is just the item or error. And that is the scenario you have here: a book or error. You also have `Maybe` (1 item or none) but I don't actually remember how to operate if none was emitted